# UI is not updating automatically, it only change after i refresh

Tags: java, android

I just started working on Android app and doing a quiz app where the user have to complete a quiz to get score. But I'm not able to update the `setText` and `setImage` for my `ResultActivity`. When I finish the quiz on `QuizActivity`, The `ResultActivity` only updates the score but does not update the text and image I want for the screen.

Here is the code and I am able to `setText` based on the "score" but I have to refresh the UI to see the changes. I am passing the score from another Activity and change the text based on the score. Please help me, thank in advance.

```
//code for QuizActivity      
private void updateQuestion(){
    if(mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()){
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 1));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 2));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber, 3));
        mButtonChoice4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice(mQuestionNumber,4));
        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
        // pass the current score to the second screen
        startActivity(intent);

        //The Following is the code for ResultActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int score = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
        SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int highscore = mypref.getInt("highscore", 0);
        if (highscore < score) {
            txtScore.setText("Your Score: " + score + " /10");
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
            editor.putInt("highscore", score);
            editor.commit();
        }
        else {
            int score1 = score + highscore;
            txtScore.setText(" Your score: " + score1 + " /10");
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = mypref.edit();
            editor1.putInt("highscore", score1);
            editor1.commit();
        }
        if (highscore == 0) {
            image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txtScore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resulttext.setText("INSTRUCTION \n" +
                "\n" +
                "1) CLICK on ‘hello!’\n" +
                "\n" +
                "2) VISIT hello\n" +
                "\n" +
                "3)EE" +
                "\n" +
                "4)EE!");
            btnscan.setText("abc!");
        }
        else if (highscore == 1 & highscore < 2) {
            resulttext.setText("Well Done!");
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bubble);
            btnscan.setText("Let's bubble on");
        }
        else if (highscore >= 3) {
            resulttext.setText("These are good practices to learn.\n" +
                "\n" +
                "Bloop bloop~");
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lightbulb);
            btnscan.setText("Let’s keep swimming");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say :  

> i'm not able to update the setText and setImage for my ResultActivity. well :

`setText` and `setImage` are methods not view. I guess you mean TextView and ImageView but which ones you mean.

Comment: Hi @Ali Zeynali, is the one in ResultActivity.if (highscore == 0){ resulttext.settext("xxx");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you trying to launch the ResultActivity with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
// pass the current score to the second screen
startActivity(intent);
```

then you want to update the activity with the code:

```
//The Following is the code for ResultActivity
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("score", 0);
SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
...
```

expecting the code to be executed after the activity is shown.

But that won't be happened because `startActivity` is **asynchronous** method. So, you need to update the data before starting the ResultActivity or update the data inside the ResultActivity.

Comment: ok thx. Any idea how i can update the data before i starting ResultActivity? sorry i am new :x

Comment: Compute the score first. Then after you've finished the computation and save it to SharedPreferences, you can start the activity.